# android httpurlconnection and jersey server formdata not playing nice

Tags: android, jersey, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I have a problem with file upload in android using `HttpUrlConnection` to jersey server.

**Changing android code to jersey http client is not and option**

Im getting `400 Bad Request - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

Android code (part of it anyway):

```
    final String BOUNDARY = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY + "; charset=" + ENCODING);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, ENCODING), true);
for (String key : request.getPOSTParams().keySet())
{
    writer.append("--").append(BOUNDARY).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(key).append("\"").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + ENCODING).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(request.getPOSTParams().get(key)).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}
```

Server Code:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
public Response upload(@NotNull @FormDataParam("photo") InputStream fileInputStream,
                       @NotNull @FormDataParam("photo") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData,
                       @FormDataParam("tags") String[] tags, @NotNull @FormDataParam("geoLongitude") Double geoLongitude,
                       @NotNull @FormDataParam("geoLatitude") Double geoLatitude,
                       @DefaultValue("false") @FormDataParam("isProfilePhoto") boolean isProfilePhoto,
                       @FormDataParam("ref_photo_id") Long refPhotoId)
{
    //other code here
}
```